# The features are not getting considered despite of adding feature selection in sklearn Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, knn

The pipeline has FeatureSelection to it, but it is not taking the updated Feature Values.

This is how my pipeline looks like:

```
# Define pipeline
pipeline = ImbPipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('feature_selection', SelectKBest(f_classif, k=5)),
    ('oversampling', SMOTE()),
    ('classifier', GridSearchCV(KNeighborsClassifier(), param_grid={
        'n_neighbors': [3, 5, 7, 9],
        'weights': ['uniform', 'distance'],
        'p': [1, 2]
    }, cv=5, scoring='accuracy'))
])
```

The preprocessor has standard scaling and outlier removal custom functions using 'ColumnTransformer'
The I have added feature_selection. Now the thing is, it is not considering the top 5 features. Using the code below, I am getting the top 5 features:

```
selected_indices = pipeline.named_steps['feature_selection'].get_support(indices=True)
print("selected features: ", selected_indices)
```

But as mentioned, the entire data is passed to SMOTE, instead of top 5 features.

How to fix this?

Comment: This shouldn't happen, since the pipeline calls the selector's `transform` method and hands the resulting 5 columns to SMOTE. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Hey, here it is:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nPTD9zfeBFfnQ0Y4kVAql5abDLCXRCmg?usp=sharing

How i figured out that it is not taking is, I have the code without pipelining. So when I run that code without feature selection, this is the exact same accuracy is what I am getting.

Comment: The example doesn't include the dataset or the definition of the outlier remover (not "reproducible"), and it's not minimal (presumably a lot of the preprocessing could be left out?).  It's possible that omitting the selection step really does lead to the same accuracy: accuracy is a somewhat coarse metric, and maybe the neighborhoods of points just aren't affected much by the others.  (It's still suspicious...)  Run `pipeline.named_steps['oversampling'].n_features_in_`.